# ways to escape { in string.format function in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am facing an issue with my code .

the thing is i want to escape { in the string.format function ...

Of course one way to escape it is to use {{ (2 curly braces)

Is there any other way possible to escape without using the double curly braces.

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why would there be another solution? `{{` is specified as *the* way of escaping braces in a format string... I can't see why the API designers would include another way.

Of course, you *could* also provide a format parameter and then populate it with a brace:

```
Dim text as String = string.Format("{0}{1}", "{", "}")
```

will give "{}" as a string, for example... but I can't see that this is a better solution.

Perhaps if you could say *why* you dislike the normal solution (double curly braces) we could advise you on an alternative - but there isn't one within the format specification "language" itself, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I wanted to know of a possible solution due to the nature of problem I was working on. The user looks up for a particular string say {0} now I use string.format to make my T-sql query which makes text = {0} . This variable text when used in next string.format causes a problem, as it is perceived as {0} not {{0}}, so I was looking for an alternative. Anyways, We have modified the entire query construction process now. Anyways, the great jon skeet replied to my question , which is definitely an honor. Thanks.

Comment: @Egalitarian: You shouldn't be including the user's value in your SQL to start with. You should use a parameterized query. Otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, that is what we realized , so we started using parameterized  query.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it this way, but not a good idea in my view.

```
    Dim str1 As String = "Print this " & Chr(123) & "0" & Chr(125) & " string"
    Dim str2 As String = "silly"
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(str1, str2))
    Console.ReadLine()
```