# vb.net Passing variables into a string using String.Format

Tags: json, vb.net

Just starting with vb.net.

I am trying to create a valid JSON string from variables.

```
Dim var1 As String = """object"":""" + anotherVar + """"
Dim var2 As String = """object2"":""" + anotherVar + """"
Dim var3 As String = """object3"":""" + anotherVar + """"

Dim jsonData As String = String.Format("{ {0}, {1}, ""somestruct"": { {2} }}", var1, var2, var3)
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. The variable jsonData is formatted incorrectly.

It should look like this if it was pure JSON.

```
{
"object": "string",
"object2": "string",
"somestruct": {
    "object3": "string"
}
```

Probably missing something silly. Totally new here, so feel free to redirect me to a better method. Thank you!

Comment: May i know why you took multiple quotations together in single string?

Comment: Why are you building the JSON yourself? It would be much easier (and better) to use any existing library for this.

Comment: This is what I'm learning... I'm sure you're right. I started looking into Newtonsoft. It gets confusing because my JSON string/object needs to be different each time based on user input, and there are several conditions that it checks. I'm going to have to keep on this and report back when I get a little more grounded. I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510128/ways-to-escape-in-string-format-function-in-vb) is a related issue..The characters "{" and "}" is the cause of the error. You have to escape these characters..

change this line

```
Dim jsonData As String = String.Format("{ {0}, {1}, ""somestruct"": { {2} }}", var1, var2, var3)
```

to

```
Dim jsonData As String = String.Format("{0} {1}, {2}, ""somestruct"": {0} {2} {3} {3}", "{", var1, var2, var3, "}")
```

or

```
Dim jsonData As String = String.Format("{{ {0}, {1}, ""somestruct"": {{ {2} }}}}", var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: I dont' know why but I got errors on this. I'm starting to look more into these JSON libraries.

Comment: can you show me the error? This link might also help you, I haven't had any JSON experience but I think it's hard if you do it from scratch.. it's in C# though, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET