# Why does String.Format give inputString not formatted error for this String

Tags: vb.net, string

So i have a VB.net String here that looks as such below.
I have another string `startId` that i wish is substituted in the appropriate places.
So i wrote the following lines.

```
Dim jsonPayloadHeaderFormat As String = "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" & "\r\n" & "Content-ID: {0}" & "\r\n" & "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={0}" & "\r\n" & "{" & "\r\n"
    String.Format(jsonPayloadHeaderFormat, startId)
```

But i get a `input string not in correct format` error.
I am new to vb.net and can't seem to get it.
Please advise.

Comment: what is the string in the variable `startId`

Comment: You have an open { at the end.  If it's intentional, then see [ways to escape { in string.format function in vb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3510128/719186).

Comment: Because of the `{\r\n` at the end. `{` indidcates that you want to begin a new element. Opening and closing braces are required.

Comment: or if the intention is to emit a `{` character, it must be escaped, using `{{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `{\r\n` at the end. `{` indidcates that you want to begin a new element. Opening **and closing braces** are required. Read the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

You also have to assign the new string which is returned from `String.Format` to a string variable:

```
Dim jsonPayloadHeaderFormat As String = "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" & "\r\n" & "Content-ID: {0}" & "\r\n" & "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={0}" & "\r\n\r\n"
Dim result As String = String.Format(jsonPayloadHeaderFormat, startId)
```